# How to let the HDFS's replica block's position be set by myself?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My goal is to let the HDFS's replica block's position node be set by myself.
After have a look at the HDFS's code ,I find the call track here (hadoop 2.2 version)

```
BlockManager.getDatanodeDescriptors(List<String>) line: 1400    
BlockManager.chooseTarget(String, int, DatanodeDescriptor, HashMap<Node,Node>, long, List<String>) line: 1378   
FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(String, long, String, ExtendedBlock, HashMap<Node,Node>, List<String>) line: 2477   
NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(String, String, ExtendedBlock, DatanodeInfo[], long, String[]) line: 555 
ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(RpcController, ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$AddBlockRequestProto) line: 387   
ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(Descriptors$MethodDescriptor, RpcController, Message) line: 59582  
ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(RPC$Server, String, Writable, long) line: 585  
ProtobufRpcEngine$Server(RPC$Server).call(RPC$RpcKind, String, Writable, long) line: 928
```

And I find the BlockManager.java hava a `chooseTarget` methods :

```
 public DatanodeDescriptor[] chooseTarget(final String src,
  final int numOfReplicas, final DatanodeDescriptor client,
  final HashMap<Node, Node> excludedNodes,
  final long blocksize, List<String> favoredNodes) throws IOException {
```

I think if I could set the `List<String> favoredNodes` 's value then my goal can be achived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the API from DistributedFileSystem.java (hadoop 2.2 version)

```
  /**
   * Same as  
   * {@link #create(Path, FsPermission, boolean, int, short, long, 
   * Progressable)} with the addition of favoredNodes that is a hint to 
   * where the namenode should place the file blocks.
   * The favored nodes hint is not persisted in HDFS. Hence it may be honored
   * at the creation time only. HDFS could move the blocks during balancing or
   * replication, to move the blocks from favored nodes. A value of null means
   * no favored nodes for this create
   */
  public HdfsDataOutputStream create(final Path f,
      final FsPermission permission, final boolean overwrite,
      final int bufferSize, final short replication, final long blockSize,
      final Progressable progress, final InetSocketAddress[] favoredNodes)
          throws IOException {
```